# CSS Issue with alignment of divs

Tags: css, html, layout

I have an issue with the following CSS. The votes I wan't to be in the same height as the Title. Although it looks like the Votes is on the same div as tags and by div. So that the 3 items to the left looks shrunken. I am quite new to it so I fail to see what I have done wrong. I had it working before I changed the height from 54 to 60 pixels, but I assume that there is something else I have added as well.

```
#containerpostsmall {
width: 800px;
height:60px;
}
.votes {
height:60px; 
width:100px;
float: left;
}
.number {
height:40px; 
text-align: center;
}
.number-text {
height:20px; 
text-align: center;
}
.texttags {
width:500px;
height:60px;
float: left;
}
.title {
height:40px;
width:500px;
font-size:32px;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}
.tagsby {
height:20px;
width:500px;
float: left;
}
.tags {
float: left;
}
.by {
float: right;
}
```

I have the following code part:

```
<div id="containerpostsmall">
<div class="votes">
    <div class="number">
        <h1>6</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="number-text">
        votes
    </div>
</div>
<div class="votes">
    <div class="number">
        <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="number-text">
        answers
    </div>
</div>
<div class="votes">
    <div class="number">
        <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="number-text">
        comments
    </div>
</div>
<div class="texttags">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="/Post/View/37">We were very tired.</a>
    </div>
    <div class="tagsby">
        <div class="tags">
                    <span style="background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #000000;"><a href="/Post/ByTag/2">Forest</a></span>
                    <span style="background-color: #ffffff; border-color: #000000;"><a href="/Post/ByTag/3">Ocean</a></span>

        </div>
        <div class="by">
            <a href="/Post/ByAuthor/30">Peter</a> |
            2013-12-03 18:56:34
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like a default h1 formatting issue. Browsers are going to apply default styling to certain elements.

I set

```
h1{
    margin: 0;
}
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kZLub/

Comment: Yep, that is correct. Thank you, will set it as answer in 7 minutes or more as it is restricted.